# One-to-Many mapping not reelected in the second table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, orm

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE USERTABLE
(
    ID        BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD  VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


CREATE TABLE PasswordHistory(
    ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    USERID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(255),
    ENTRYTIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES USERTABLE(ID)
);
```

User Table

```
@DynamicInsert(value = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "usertable")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty
    @NotBlank(message = "User name must be provided")
    @Column(name= "USERNAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "username", value = "Name of user (must be unique)", required = true, example = "user_name", position = 1)
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty
    @NotBlank(message = "Password must be provided")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "password", value = "Password of the user", required = true, example = "password", position = 2)
    private String password;


    @JsonProperty
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'CUSTOMER'")
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    List<PasswordHistory> passwordHistories;

//getters, setters

}
```

Password log table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "passwordhistory")
public class PasswordHistory {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private Long userId;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "password", value = "Password of the user", required = true, example = "password", position = 2)
    private String password;


    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty
    private Timestamp entrytime;

    public PasswordHistory() {

    }
//GetterSetter

}
```

In user Service

```
public class UserPrincipalService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordHistoryRepository passwordHistoryRepository;


    @Autowired
    public UserPrincipalService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordHistoryRepository passwordHistoryRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordHistoryRepository = passwordHistoryRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User savedUser = findUserByUsername(username);
        return new UserPrincipal(savedUser);
    }


    public User findUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    public void changePassword(String username, String newpassword, String oldpassword) throws PasswordMismatchException, OldThreePasswordMatchException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));

        if (!oldpassword.equals(user.getPassword())) throw new PasswordMismatchException("Old password incorrect");

        List<PasswordHistory> passwordHistories = passwordHistoryRepository.findTop3ByUserIdOrderByEntrytimeDesc(user.getId());
        for (PasswordHistory passwordHistory : passwordHistories)
            if (oldpassword.equals(passwordHistory.getPassword())) {
                throw new OldThreePasswordMatchException("Password should not match with last three passwords");
            }

        user.setPassword(newpassword);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

In controller:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/user/password")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Change password")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Password has been changed"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Record not found", response = ErrorResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Server cannot process request due to client error", response = ErrorResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Something failed in the server", response = ErrorResponse.class)
    })
    public String changePassword(Principal principal,
                                 @RequestParam("newpassword") String newpassword,
                                 @RequestParam("oldpassword") String oldpassword) throws PasswordMismatchException, OldThreePasswordMatchException {
        String username = principal.getName();
        userPrincipalService.changePassword(username, newpassword, oldpassword);
        return "Password has been updated successfully";
    }
```

I have done one to many mapping between user and password log table. Password log is basically for auditing the passwords and validating.

Password Log table should be updated automatically when any change or new password entry is done in user table. But it is not getting reflected in the database

I am using **JPArepository**

Comment: Please add code showing how you persist/update these entities.

Comment: I am using  Hibernate for persisting entities. Via JPA.

Comment: what are you doing in the user.setPassword() ?

Comment: Just updating the existing password.

Comment: public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

Comment: What is your assumption here ? That set a new password will automatically create a new password history entry ?

Comment: Yeah. Any time a new user is signing up or changing password the log should be entered in the table.

Comment: Peaky... what about this one?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the most important step : create a new entry in the password history when setting a new password.

Something like :

```
public void setPassword(String password) { 
    this.password = password; 
    history.add(new PasswordHistory(password); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just need to anottate the method `changePassword`

```java
    @Transactional
    public void changePassword(String username, String newpassword, String oldpassword) throws PasswordMismatchException, OldThreePasswordMatchException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));

        if (!oldpassword.equals(user.getPassword())) throw new PasswordMismatchException("Old password incorrect");

        List<PasswordHistory> passwordHistories = passwordHistoryRepository.findTop3ByUserIdOrderByEntrytimeDesc(user.getId());
        for (PasswordHistory passwordHistory : passwordHistories)
            if (oldpassword.equals(passwordHistory.getPassword())) {
                throw new OldThreePasswordMatchException("Password should not match with last three passwords");
            }

        user.setPassword(newpassword);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).